# How does the Attack stat affect damage calculation?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon

I have been having problems trying to figure out how the Attack stats work for Pokémon Red Rescue Team.

I have a Lv. 44 Swampert, with around 70 Attack. I also have a Lv. 26 Kyogre (last time I checked), with around the same amount of attack. The thing is, in the Magma Cavern dungeon, my Swampert does ~50-55 damage. My Kyogre does, in the same dungeon, ~25-30 damage.

Are there secret attack stats that I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: What attacks were they using and on which Pokemon? It may have been a type-effectiveness modifier.

Comment: @Vemonus Just normal. no moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your Kyogre does less damage, according to the calculation given [here](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/221416/damage-determined-pokemon-mystery-dungeon-blue-rescue-team), is that the attacking Pokemon's *level* is taken into account when calculating damage. As you mentioned in the question, your Kyogre was much lower level than your Swampert, which would explain the vast difference in damage output despite similar stats.

> Here is the formula for calculation of damage in PMD:
>
> Damage = (((D2)-C)+10)+((DD)*3276/65536)
>
> Where,
>
> - A = Attacker’s Attack or Special Attack
> - **B = Attacker’s level**
> - C = The target’s Defense or Special Defense
> - D = ((A-C)/8)+(B*43690/65536)

Comment: Does it matter which game? I have red rescue team, not blue.

Comment: @Yoshi24517 no, I believe they are similar in vein to the way the core series games work. The same game mechanics, just different Pokémon and slightly altered stories.